# Mapstruct detecting modified nodes

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct 1.3.1-FINAL and mapping 2 complex custom objects - `Employee "source" and Employee "update"`. Once I apply the "update" on "source" , is there a way I can find out what all nodes were updated in source so that I can just process the ones that were updated? My Employee object is quite complex with lots of custom attributes but I just want to further process only the ones that are modified in "source".

Answer (score 0):

Well.. if `Source` is empty (only nulls) you'll know by the objects that are non null. I guess that's a bit too trivial.

If `Source` has values prior to your update, you might want to do the mapping twice, once as update on the actual source, once on an empty object that can serve as a "template". Now you can traverse the tree for both the template and source and by means of the objects set in template you'll know what's updated in source.